# negative pell's equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, pell-type-equations

If $d$ is divisible by a prime $p \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$. show that the equation $x^2-dy^2=-1$ has no solution.

So far I have learn only positive Pell's equation but not negative Pell's equation. We know that in positive Pell's equation, it always has a solution but not the case for negative Pell's equation.

Can anyone give some hints on how to tackle this question?

Comment: Do you know what quadratic residues are, Legendre symbol?

Comment: @WillJagy: Yup, I do learn that. So the negative pell's equation  have no solution iff the Legendre symbol $(\frac{-1}{d})=-1$?

Comment: When $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ and $x^2 \equiv -1 \pmod p$, what is $x^{p-1}\pmod p$ ?

Comment: @achillehui: $x^{p-1} \equiv -1 (\mod p)$?

Comment: Yup, and this contradicts with [Fermat's little theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose a solution exists. Then reducing mod $p$ we find that $x^2 \equiv -1 \bmod p$. Then $\left(\frac{-1}{p}\right) = 1$. However $p\equiv 3 \bmod 4$ so this is a contradiction.